# String Split Golang

Tags: string, go, split

I have a string that has stored JSON data and i want to split the data in 2 parts:

Below is the string:

```
Data:{"Event": Hello,
"IsEventRunning": TRUE,
}
{"EventDetails": MG stan,"help": True
}
```

I want to break the string from "EventDetails" and save it in a separate variable, Kindly help

Comment: The text shown in the question is not JSON.

Comment: i want to separate a JSON stored as string from a Json key and store it in another variable @CeriseLimón

Comment: Assuming that you have JSON, use the encoding/json package to decode the JSON, fetch the field from the result, and split the string using strings.Split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below link:

Golang supports cutting of string

https://gosamples.dev/split-string/

`Strings.Cut` will help you dividing a string, strings.Cut supports only for versions above 1.19